# Get Data when empty Table is found in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this loan application I am creating, I have two major tables, the `loans_request` table, and the `loans_account` table, the the way the application works is this, when a loan request is made it is saved in the `loans_request` table and when a it has been approved and payments are made, payments are stored in the `loans_account` table.

I created an SQL that looks like this:

```
 SELECT  lr.RequestId,
    lr.SapNumber,
    lr.AmountRequested,
    lr.InterestRate,
    lr.AmountRequested * lr.InterestRate /100 +lr.AmountRequested AS AmountDue,
    lr.AmountRequested * lr.InterestRate /100 AS Interest,
    lr.DateDue,
    IFNULL(SUM(la.LoanAmount), 0) AS AmountPaid,
    (lr.AmountRequested * lr.InterestRate /100 +lr.AmountRequested) - SUM(la.LoanAmount) AS Debt,
    members.FirstName,
    members.Surname,
    members.OtherNames,
    la.SoftDelete
FROM loans_account la
INNER JOIN loans_request lr
ON la.LoanRequestId = lr.RequestId
INNER JOIN members
ON lr.SapNumber = members.SapNumber
WHERE lr.SoftDelete <> '1'
AND la.SoftDelete <> '1'
AND lr.Approved = '1'
AND lr.PaymentComplete = '0'
GROUP BY la.LoanRequestId;
```

The problem with this code is, when a loan request is made, because no payments has been made to the `loans_account` table, it returns an empty result, hence meaning no outstanding loan debts.

I want the code to instead tell me that no payments has been made on a particular loan if it meets all the `where clauses`, I want the Debt to be calculated only when  `la.SoftDelete` <> 1, because it means the payment has been reverted when `la.SoftDelete` =1.

I hope my question is constructive enough, I would appreciate all answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Move the `where` conditions into a `case` statement in the `select`:

```
 SELECT  lr.RequestId,
    lr.SapNumber,
    lr.AmountRequested,
    lr.InterestRate,
    lr.AmountRequested * lr.InterestRate /100 +lr.AmountRequested AS AmountDue,
    lr.AmountRequested * lr.InterestRate /100 AS Interest,
    lr.DateDue,
    IFNULL(SUM(la.LoanAmount), 0) AS AmountPaid,
    (lr.AmountRequested * lr.InterestRate /100 +lr.AmountRequested) - SUM(la.LoanAmount) AS Debt,
    members.FirstName,
    members.Surname,
    members.OtherNames,
    la.SoftDelete,
    (case when lr.SoftDelete <> '1' AND la.SoftDelete <> '1' AND lr.Approved = '1' AND lr.PaymentComplete = '0'
          then 'None' else 'Some'
     end) as Outstanding
FROM loans_account la INNER JOIN
     loans_request lr
     ON la.LoanRequestId = lr.RequestId INNER JOIN
     members
     ON lr.SapNumber = members.SapNumber
GROUP BY la.LoanRequestId;
```

Note:  this assumes that the join's are not filtering the rows you want.  If so, you need `left outer join` and to switch the logic to:

```
    (case when lr.SoftDelete = '1' OR la.SoftDelete = '1' OR lr.Approved <> '1' OR lr.PaymentComplete = '0'
          then 'Some'
          else 'None'
     end) as Outstanding
FROM loans_account la LEFT JOIN
     loans_request lr
     ON la.LoanRequestId = lr.RequestId LEFT JOIN
     members
     ON lr.SapNumber = members.SapNumber;
```

(I switched the logic so non-matches would go in the `none` category.)

Comment: Thanks....But this means rows would be returned even when they do not meet the condition, then I would have to filter out from my codes by checking 'some' and 'none' right?

Comment: And also it still returns deleted loan payments when 'la.SoftDelete' is = 1

Comment: @Ramos1116 . . . Then add the appropriate filters into with the `where` or `on` clause.  This query addresses your question:  "if it meets all the where clauses".

Comment: Yeah, but what I really want is for the Summation not to occur for places where la.SoftDelete <> '1' fails